# send data via GPRS in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, sockets, gprs

I'm working on a project that I need to send some data to the server via GPRS . I've IP number and Port, but I don't know how should I send my data. How can I do it? 
I want a code for sending data to the server or if there is sample project. 
(I use VS 2008 and .NET 3.5)
thank's to all.

Comment: What you've tried: nothing. What you want: someone to give you code. You're off to a good start on this site ...

Comment: No, sorry but you'r wrong . I looked many sites such as MSDN, this site, Code Project and ...  but I couldn't find my answer. After many searches I asked my question.

Comment: I find this code Socket m_socClient = new Socket(
            AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse("31.47.53.12");
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 2036);
            m_socClient.Connect(remoteEP); // No exception!   But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer of my Qustion :

```
private void SendData(string value)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("31.47.53.12", 2036))
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

        }
```

Comment: well done for solving it. for future reference, write what you've tried, and put any attempts you had made with the question asked. So many people just post questions and say "givez me the codezzzz" ...